# Disposal tripping breaker and it’s brand new. It comes on for a second but then trips breaker

Tags: electrical

Plumber just installed new disposal and it keeps tripping breaker

Comment: We need  a little more help here! Is it replacing another disposal that was also tripping? Is the current rating the same? If cord connected did you try to plug into countertop circuit?

Comment: More words please. Explain in detail, is this a replacement? What brand model, How is it  getting its power?  Etc.

Comment: What did the plumber have to say about this?  Is he sure the new disposal is good?

Comment: Is the tripping breaker in the electric panel and is it a GFCI breaker?

Comment: Are you sure it runs for a whole second then blows, or could it be that it blows sooner but takes a moment to spin-down?

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it? Is this disposal on its own circuit, or does it share a circuit with something else?

Comment: Did you ask the plumber to come back to fix his work?